# SelectList not selecting the selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure what's happening, but when I specify a selected item in my select list, it's not being assigned the "selected" attribute in the markup.

My model has a property called PlanningYears, which is a List containing 2011, 2012, 2013, and 2014 for values.

I want the current year to be selected, and I have tried:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlanningYears , new SelectList(Model.PlanningYears, DateTime.Now.Year), null, null)
```

But to no avail.

This sounds like it could be related to: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/4932

Can anyone think of a workaround?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{    
    var testModel = new int?[]
        {
            2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2014
        };

    var current = DateTime.Now.Year;

    var list = testModel.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.ToString(),
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Selected = (x == current)
        });
}

@Html.DropDownList("testModel", list)
```

it's work :)

Comment: x doesn't have a .Year() method, x is a nullable int. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

@{
                        var list = Model.PlanningYears.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = x.ToString(),
                            Value = x.ToString(),
                            Selected = x == DateTime.Now.Year
                        }).ToList();                       
                    }
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlanningYears, list)

Comment: It does work. I guess there is no way to select an item using the DropDownListFor helper? We need to change the name attribute of the dropdown for item selection to work? Seems strange to me...

Comment: Model for DropDownListFor must be int or int?, not int?[]

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPlanningYear, list)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you will need two properties in your view model for any dropdown list:  A list of items to display and a string or int to bind the selected value to.

So in your case you need the following two properties in your model:

```
public int PlanningYear { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> PlanningYears { get; set; }
```

There is no overload of the DropDownListFor helper to set a default selected value, so you should do this in your controller:

```
viewModel.PlanningYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

Then your helper in the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PlanningYear, Model.PlanningYears)
```